# webviews onclicklistener not triggered in my dialog

Tags: android, webview, onclicklistener

When clicking in my webview of my dialog nothing happens.

Any suggestions / help on this ?

Here my code:

```
dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.quicktextviewerlayout);

webView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

setWebViewTextSize();

webView.loadData("No Text", "text/html", "utf-8");
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
some stuff here
    }
});
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

ImageView imageView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.closebutton);
imageView.getLayoutParams().width = Layouts.getPixelPerCm()/3;
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = Layouts.getPixelPerCm()/3;
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss(); <- works fine here.
    }
});

webView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO : isnt triggered !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        interactActivity.openBookFromQuickTextViewerState();
    }
});
```

Comment: Clicking on your WebView will only result in some action if the HTML you are displaying in your WebView initiates it, such as a <a href='... link.  If you click on a link in your webview, then it should cause shouldOverrideUrlLoading to be called, and there you can choose what you want to do.

Comment: ShouldOverrideLoading works perfect for links, but that is not what I want. I would like to trigger any click, that is not related to a link. Say if I click on a text which is not a link, I like to maximize the webview for example.

Comment: WebViews are very complex objects, they have an internal ScrollView and need to respond to clicks and drags and any number of other user interaction events.  Therefore, they intercept all user interaction events, so, you can't override them.  What some people do, if they don't need the WebView to be very responsive, is place a clear button on top of the WebView, that way, the WebView can display the content, and the button can handle the click event.  But, that will mean that any links or dynamic elements in the WebView's contents won't respond to user interaction, which isn't desirable.